# Como usar cookies em javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, cookies

Sei criar cookies em JavaScript, mas não sei como aplicar eles em algum projeto. Alguém poderia postar um exemplo de como usar cookies?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217192/javascript-redirecionar-e-setar-cookies me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 8):

Como respondi em [**Gravar cookie e ler seu valor ao aceder ao web site para verificar se expirado**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57855/3635)

Você deve usar `document.cookie` para criar os cookies conforme a necessidade e o script deve rodar em um servidor (como Apache por exemplo), acesso local (protocolo `file://`) geralmente não funciona com cookies.

> note que alguns navegadores bloqueiam cookies gerados pelo `http://localhost`, para contornar o problema use o endereço `http://127.0.0.1`

Para criar um cookie devemos usar os parâmetros suportados são:

- `;path=` deve conter o caminho/path HTTP que poderá ser usado para limitar aonde o cookie deve ser acessível
- `;expires=` deve conter data em formato GMT de quando vai expirar
- `;max-age=` deve conter conter o tempo em segundos de quando o cookie deve expirar, não é necessário usar `max-age` e `expires` ao mesmo tempo
- `;secure` especifica que o cookie só deve funcionar sobre o protocolo HTTPS

O nome do cookie (chave) e o valor podem ser codificados com `encodeURIComponent` para evitar que caracteres como espaços ou `;` façam os dados se perderem.

Exemplo de com como criar um cookie:

```
document.cookie="<chave>=<valor>; expires=<data para expirar>; path=<caminho HTTP>";
```

Um exemplo de cookie que deve expirar em 31/12/2018 as 23:59:59 (em GMT):

```
document.cookie="chave=valor; expires=Mon, 31 Dec 2018 23:59:59 GMT;path=/"
```

Note que talvez ao invés de cookies você pode usar `localStorage` e `sessionStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Por exemplo com `sessionStorage`:

```
// Salva dados
sessionStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");

// Pega os dados
alert( "foo = " + sessionStorage.getItem("foo"));
```

Por exemplo com `localStorage`:

```
// Salva dados
localStorage.setItem("baz", "bar");

// Pega os dados
alert( "foo = " + localStorage.getItem("baz"));
```

A diferença entre `sessionStorage` e `localStorage` é que o primeiro expira sempre que o navegador é fechado, o segundo se mantém

> **Nota:** se quiser usar `localStorage` com tempo para expirar veja esta outra resposta que criei [**Como fazer para que o Local Storage expire?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179259/3635)

---

Mas como a questão sobre cookies, irei mostrar um exemplo com tal, então criei as seguintes funções:

```
function getCookie(k) {
    var cookies = " " + document.cookie;
    var key = " " + k + "=";
    var start = cookies.indexOf(key);

    if (start === -1) return null;

    var pos = start + key.length;
    var last = cookies.indexOf(";", pos);

    if (last !== -1) return cookies.substring(pos, last);

    return cookies.substring(pos);
}

function setCookie(k, v, expira, path) {
    if (!path) path = "/";

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expira * 1000));

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v) + "; expires=" + d.toUTCString() + "; path=" + path;
}
```

Para definir o seu cookie de ID, faça isto:

```
setCookie("chave", "valor");
```

Para ler o cookie que chamamos de `chave` faça assim:

```
var resultado = getCookie("chave");
console.log(resultado); //Exibe o resultado ou exibe null se tiver expirado ou não for acessível a partir do PATH da URL atual
```

Para definir um tempo para expirar o cookie faça assim:

```
setCookie("foo", "baz", 3600);//Expira o cookie "foo" em uma hora
```

Para restringir o cookie somente a certas *caminhos HTTP* (rotas) use assim:

```
setCookie("bar", "baz", false, "/pasta2/");//o cookie só estara acessível em urls como http://site/pasta2/*
```

Se quiser definir um tempo para expirar em um PATH especifico use assim:

```
setCookie("bar", "baz", 86400, "/pasta3/");//o cookie só estará acessível em urls como http://site/pasta3/* e irá expirar em 24 horas
```